# How to delete rows from a certain table in the following situation? see photo

Tags: mysql

[image]

So, I need to delete the details of an artist where the gallery doesn't own any of their art anymore. How do I do that? Can it be done with `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`? Even though the two tables are not related directly. Or should I add `ArtistName` as a foreign key to `BorrowedObject` first?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to DELETE the artist under these circumstances? What if the gallery wants to own that artists work in the future, or borrow works? Or review whose work they have owned historically?

Comment: Why subsets of OBJECT?

Comment: Because the gallery has objects that are borrowed from other collections for the time being. The gallery also owns objects.

Comment: the gallery doesn't want to keep information about artists who's art objects are not owned by them.

Comment: anyway, it's a school project and that's part of the transaction requests from the scenario brief :)

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with thousands of reason, to not delete an artist information, even if you don't use any of their arts. Maybe in the future, you will use your data archive do to some statistics, or get a list of all artist you have bought some item from them or from another, and other reasons.

But if you want it, here it is:

You can use `not in`:

```
DELETE FROM artist
WHERE artistName NOT IN
(SELECT artistName FROM object t1 INNER JOIN gallery_object t2
on t1.OUnique_code = t2.OUnique_code)
```

Comment: I also had this in mind:
DELETE FROM *Artist WHERE artistname NOT IN
(SELECT artistname FROM Object NATURAL JOIN GalleryOwnedObject ON Object.OuniqueCode = GalleryOwnedObject.OuniqueCode)